# Django add friends to query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a query where I retrieve all the "activity" for the logged in user and his "friends" sorted by most recent. (friends are connected using Django-Simple-Friends).

The following query works great for retrieving all the activity for the logged in user sorted by most recent but I am not sure how to also include the user's connected "friends".

```
activity = Activity.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-created_date')
```

My activity class is:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    activity_type = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I appreciate the time and expertise.

Comment: In which table is stored the Users' connected friends?

Comment: The Users' connected friends is stored in the "friendship" table created by Django-Simple-Friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the query this way:

```
friend_user_list = list(friends_list) + [request.user]
activity = Activity.objects.filter(user__in=friend_user_list).order_by('-created_date')
```

What I'm trying to do there is concatenate to lists, `[request.user]` and the list of their friends (assuming that `friends` is the related name of the Friendship relationship) and the `user__in` should modify the WHERE condition to allow all users in the list to satisfy the query.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting the error: 'User' object has no attribute 'friends' I also tried "friendship" in place of "friends" and I get the error:'Friendship' object has no attribute 'all' Any thoughts on what I can try?

Comment: How do you normally get the friends for a user?

Comment: I haven't needed to to generate that list yet but the documentation give this example to obtain all a users' friends: friends = Friendship.objects.friends_of(user1)

Comment: Well, what I try do with the query is to conform a list with the user and it's friends. Then, pass it to the filter function using the  __in accesor. You can try this: `user__in=[request.user]+Friendship.objects.friends_of(request.user)` inside the filter.

Comment: I think this is getting really close. I works if I pass in user__in=[request.user] OR user__in=Friendship.objects.friends_of(request.user) Should I try to create one list outside of the query and then pass in that list? (I'm fairly new to programming so I'm not always sure about best approaches)

Comment: It's ok to create the list outside and then pass it to the filter. If it worked already notify me to correct the answer :)

Comment: ok now I'm feeling kind of stupid. I'm trying to combine the two lists. Seems pretty straight forward:  friends_list = Friendship.objects.friends_of(request.user)
 user_list = [request.user]
 friend_user_list = friends_list + user_list But now I am gettin the error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QuerySet' and 'list' Do I need to import something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28849/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-bbrooke)

Comment: just figured it out: friend_user_list = list(friends_list) + user_list I really appreciate all your time and feedback!